# Is it possible to delay sending an ack in netty's socket.io implementation?

Tags: java, socket.io, netty

While using https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio I'm using a queue and a thread pool to process the received data (sorry about the formatting stackoverflow is complaining about spaces when I put the code on different lines):

```
server.addEventListener("NEW_SELL_ORDER", SellOrder.class, (client, data, ackSender) -> actionQueue.add((connection) -> this.onNewSellOrder(connection, client, data, ackSender)));
```

The problem is that `ackSender` isn't usable anymore because the threadpool is processing the request a split second later.

Resulting in the question: is it possible to delay sending an ack in netty's socket.io implementation?

See: https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/blob/master/src/main/java/com/corundumstudio/socketio/AckRequest.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it possible to handle ack sending manually.

1. You should switch ack mode to manual in configuration.

   `config.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL)`
2. Send ack by yourself:

   ```
   server.addEventListener("NEW_SELL_ORDER", SellOrder.class, (client, data, ackSender) ->  {
          if (ackRequest.isAckRequested()) {
               ackRequest.sendAckData(...);
          }
   });
   ```

Comment: How to send automatic ack ? config.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO); is not enough.